# Account suspended because college friend offered bounty and upvoted a few of my answers

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, appeal

I don't know if moderators are actually trying to understand my predicament here, but a few years back I had a friend from college who used to share me the links of his questions to answer questions on Stack Overflow. He might have offered me a bounty and few upvotes. I just got to know this because those questions were deleted by moderators. I discussed this matter with him and got to know his account was deleted by moderators.

Can any moderator please help me here?

Comment: This question is about appealing an account suspension, nothing more nothing less. Removed the tags that weren't relevant.

Comment: It certainly looks like a busted voting ring. The voting patterns look like that of a voting ring (e.g., roughly the same amount of votes on multiple days, not necessarily consecutive days). For example, on [2022-07-17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10216112/himanshuman?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) there were upvotes on nine answers. Six of the answers that got upvotes now have one less upvote. This is very unlikely to happen by chance (e.g., *random* user accounts deleted (reversal of votes by random users would required an edit)). Or were they reverted as serial upvoting soon after?

Comment: If you wish to ask for more clarifications, you might consider reposting your question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Alain Reve: There will be [a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10216112/himanshuman?tab=profile) [slight delay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6gN1uO8w6Y&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&index=12&t=5m34s).

Comment: “I assure you moderators neither did it ever happen again from this account nor will ever happen again in the future.” - You made this implicit promise when you created your account but you broke it, you knew voting for your friend’s contributions were not allowed, your voting ring was broken up.  Your lucky your account wasn’t permanently suspended. Hope it was worth it to be forever seen has someone linked to voting irregularities

Answer (score 26):

SO moderator here, not previously involved in your case. I've reviewed the history here. You were [sent a message](https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/94566#94566) describing your suspension, as with all suspensions.

We don't disclose our methods for determining when vote fraud is occurring. The moderators involved in your suspension saw convincing evidence of voting fraud and acted appropriately.

Your best path forward is to wait for the end of the suspension, and explain to your friend that targeted voting is not helpful. Also, note that deleting and recreating accounts won't work to circumvent a suspension (in fact, it'll only make things worse).

Comment: @Himanshuman What account are you concerned about? I see 111 rep on your SF account and no undeleted posts elsewhere.

Comment: OP won't get notification for your comment since they didn't comment on the answer, guess you meant to post it under the question.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard long story short, am I going to get my meta stackoverflow account back after suspension ends? currently I am getting a 500 error when opening the website

Comment: @Himanshuman your MSO account is empty (only one comment) so not sure what you mean. Anyway, yes, after suspension period is over, you get full access again, just like before, nothing is lost. However, if you'll keep breaking the rules (e.g. try to create new accounts to keep using the site), you risk having your account **deleted** and thus losing it forever.

Comment: @Himanshuman note, very important: if your friend is using the same IP as you, moderators might and most likely identify this as your action, they have no way to know it's actually somebody else. You really better find a solution for this, and kindly ask your college to not use SO until you find a way to have a different IP address.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard so currently when I am trying to answer the question I get two error messages `1. This account is temporarily suspended 2. 
Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question.` That's because few4-5 of my question/answers were deleted by moderator because I was answering question asked by my friend's account and also because some of the answer contained paragraph copied from quora and various other articles, but please note that all those answers had credits/source/reference.

Comment: But those answer were still deleted, so my question is when the suspension period finally gets over, wil the answer ban also be lifted or am I banned permanently from answering now, I guess if that is the case then I would delete all my accounts and start afresh

Comment: @Himanshuman the answer ban is something totally separate from account suspension, so no, it won't be lifted when your suspension is over. However, it's not permanent, editing existing answers to get them more upvotes can lift the ban.

Comment: So if I edit the answers, they are anyway in deleted stated and cannot be shown to the user since the moderator himself has deleted it, how will I get upvotes on the same then? because those answer anyway will not be visible to anyone

Comment: @Himanshuman currently you can't do anything on Stack Overflow for one year. There's nothing anyone here can do, your last option is to send [contact us form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), explain everything in details, and hope Stack Exchange staff will intervene and lift your suspension. And there is really nothing more anyone here, even moderators, can do to help you.